# pcap_open() not usable in libpcap

Tags: libpcap

I want to create an application by libpcap in Qt in Kali linux. I create similar application in windows & does work.

I download & install libpcap. Now, Qt recognizes pcap.h but some functions & constants does not work. like as:

```
pcap_open - PCAP_OPENFLAG_PROMISCUOUS - pcap_findalldevs_ex - PCAP_SRC_IF_STRING - _snprintf_s.
```

The compiler errors similar as 'sth' was not declared in this scope.
I use below headers but above errors apppear.

```
#define HAVE_REMOTE
#define WPCAP
#include <pcap.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
```

Comment: Can you provide the exact compiler error message?

Comment: Thanks dear ScoPi.

I have new problem that i`m saying in Dear Startup comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinPcap adds some APIs not available in libpcap (and versions of libpcap newer than the version upon which the latest WinPcap release is based have APIs not available in WinPcap).

`pcap_open()` is one of those APIs; it is ***NOT*** available in libpcap.  You must either use `pcap_open_live()` or, in libpcap 1.x, `pcap_create()` and `pcap_activate()`.

libpcap also doesn't currently support remote packet capture.

Answer (score 1):

add
 LIBS += -lpcap 
at the end of your .pro file. It will solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot dear @Startup.
I added this but the project does not run.
in application output:
/root/Qt-Project/build-LinuxBasedPacketCapturing-Desktop_Qt_5_2_1_GCC_32bit-Debug/LinuxBasedPacketCapturing: error while loading shared libraries: libpcap.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: @Mohammad apt-get install libsqlite3-dev, check your /usr/lib whether libpcap.so is present there or not. other wise you have to link the location of libpcap.so

Comment: I uesd locate command in linux & responds. some of response is here:

/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpcap.so.0.8
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpcap.so.1.3.0

I added LIBS += -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpcap.so.1.3.0
but the application output says like above.

Comment: ls /usr/lib | grep libpcap , check libpacp versio, it will display libpcap.so.1.3.0 or something else    then ln -s /usr/lib/libpcap.so.1.3.0 libpcap.so.1.  try it may solve your issue

Comment: Exccuse me. I was testing on wrong project.
the errors of My first post does not solve.

I think above founctions & constant are not compatible with libpcap (just in winpcap). because another functions workes. Right?

Comment: "I think above founctions & constant are not compatible with libpcap (just in winpcap). because another functions workes. Right?"  Yes.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I searched & found some functions in winpcap does not work in  libpcap (As Guy Harris said).

For Qt programmer in linux, they have to add below code to .pro file:

```
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib/ -lpcap
```