# Where is pcap_open() function? [C++][WinPcap]

Tags: c++, network-programming, winpcap

```cpp
/* Open the device */
if ( (adhandle= pcap_open(d->name,
                          65536,
                          PCAP_OPENFLAG_PROMISCUOUS,
                          1000,
                          NULL,
                          errbuf)
   ) == NULL)
   {
        fprintf(stderr,"\nUnable to open the adapter. %s is not supported by WinPcap\n", d->name);
        /* Free the device list */
        pcap_freealldevs(alldevs);
        return -1;
   }
```

This code is in [this](https://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_412/html/group__wpcap__tut3.html). 
I included `pcap.h`. 
But I can't use `pcap_open()` function. 
`identifier "pcap_open" is undefined`

Please help me.

Comment: Did you actually look in `pcap.h` to see if `pcap_open()` was defined in it? Perhaps you are running into an issue similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22601087/)?

Comment: You don't really provide a lot of information. All i can really say is winpcap is deprecated. Try npcap instead.